# Emacs: How can I customize eglot to make it autocomplete \ac{} when in latex-mode?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, latex

I'm experimentinng with eglot and digestif as my completion framework for LaTEX on emacs. I'm starting to understand how it works for `\cite{}` and `\ref{}`, but I use acronyms profusely and would like to have hints for my acronyms.

Is there any way to add a function to complete inside a `\ac{}`?